# How can I resolve the error in using WhenEvent to solve the cooling of liquid, where the cooling coefficient changes for some time?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, event-detection

I am trying to solve the cooling of liquid in which the cooling coefficient changes for some time. I attempted to solve it using WhenEvent, but it is showing an error.

```
     (* Constants *)
       ambientTemperature = 25; (* °C *)
    initialTemperature = 90; (* °C *)
    coolingCoefficient = 0.1; (* Cooling coefficient *)

     (* Function to calculate the temperature at a given time *)
    temperature[t_] := ambientTemperature + (initialTemperature - ambientTemperature) 
    Exp[- 
    coolingCoefficient t]

    (* Change in heat transfer coefficient event *)
     changeCoefficientEvent = WhenEvent[t == 2, coolingCoefficient = 0.2]

     (* Solve the differential equation with WhileEvent *)
     solution = NDSolve[{temperature'[t] == -coolingCoefficient (temperature[t] - 
     ambientTemperature), temperature[0] == initialTemperature, changeCoefficientEvent}, 
     temperature, {t, 0, 60}]

    (* Plotting the cooling curve *)
    Plot[temperature[t] /. solution, {t, 0, 60},
    AxesLabel -> {"Time (minutes)", "Temperature (°C)"},
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Blue],
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, initialTemperature}], Point[{60, 
    ambientTemperature}]},
    AspectRatio -> 1/2
                    ]
```

Comment: Why not just make `coolingCoefficient` a `Piecewise` function of `t`?

Comment: You first define "temperature" and then later you use it as a unknown function in "NDSolve"